# Bundling recursively all js from a folder using Vite 4

Tags: gulp, vite

I'm new on Vite and I try to migrating a template using gulp/handlebars to vite.

Is there a way to do the same that this Gulp code but using Vite 4:

```js
const javascript = function () {
    const out = paths.baseDistAssets + "js/";

    // vendor.min.js
    src([
        paths.baseDistAssets + "vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
        paths.baseDistAssets + "vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
        paths.baseDistAssets + "vendor/simplebar/simplebar.min.js"
    ])
        .pipe(concat("vendor.js"))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(dest(out));


    // copying and minifying all other js
    src([paths.baseSrcAssets + "js/**/*.js", "!" + paths.baseSrcAssets + "js/template-layout.js", "!" + paths.baseSrcAssets + "js/template-main.js"])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(dest(out));


    // app.js (template-main.js + template-layout.js)
    return src([paths.baseSrcAssets + "js/template-main.js", paths.baseSrcAssets + "js/template-layout.js"])
        .pipe(concat("app.js"))
        .pipe(dest(out))
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(dest(out));
};
```

So basically, I want to create the `vendor.min.js` and `app.min.js`.